# Postfix forward specific mails from HOLD queue

Tags: linux, postfix, redhat, centos6

Is it possible in postfix to forward messages from the hold queue by referencing to them by their file name?

The best way would be by a terminal command.

Even better would be a python command.

If that's not possible editing the main.cf would be a considered option.

**Background:**

I have a python script which gives me a dynamic list of filenames of the mails in the hold queue which should be forwarded to a specific address for further examination before being delivered to their final destination.

e.g. of a file list from the hold queue

49C0B406D7

1F3BD40685

9F847406D8

61C63406D6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use shell command

```
postcat -qbh queueid | sendmail -f sender forward_address@example.com
```

Source: [man postcat](http://www.postfix.org/postcat.1.html), [man sendmail](http://www.postfix.org/sendmail.1.html) and this thread [Postfix: change sender in queued messages](https://serverfault.com/questions/623211/postfix-change-sender-in-queued-messages/623266#623266)

Comment: I had to leave out the -b and -h option as these aren't present in my postfix installation